# Only fields matching regexp

Tags: grafana, jsonata

I wonder what is the best and more efficient way to filter out fields with regular expression. My jsons looks like:

```json
{
    "const": {
        "bt_L1": 1,
        "bt_L2": 1,
        "bt_L3": 0,
        "bt_R1": 0,
        "bt_R2": 0,
        "bt_R3": 1
    }
}
```

I would need to get only the fields that:

Start with "bt_L"
The content is 1
Then I need to put them in a single element as a string removing "bt_" as follows:

"L1, L2"

Looks very tricky, any ideas over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not pretty, but it works:

```
$spread(const)[* = 1].$keys() 
  ~> $filter(λ($k) { $substring($k, 0, 4) = "bt_L" }) 
  ~> $map(λ($k) { $substring($k, 3) }) 
  ~> $join(", ")
```

Comment: it does work. Thanks for that.